# AngularJs: How to detect which option caused the change event?

Tags: angularjs, multiple-select

I have a **multiple** select control and I want to be able to prevent the selection of multiple items **within a group**. Here's the code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" 
    data-ng-model="dlgData.selItem" 
    data-ng-change="itemChange()"
    data-ng-options="item.value as item.text group by item.group for item in dlgData.itemList">
</select>
```

This is a multiple select control so dlgData.selItem will potentially contain an array of selected items.

I want to limit the selection to one item per group, thus, in the change event I want to check to see if the user has added a second item from a previously selected group, i.e. check to see if dlgData.selItem contains values from the same group,

Question: How do I determine the item that caused the change event?

For single select dropdowns I would just check the model but in this case the model (dlgData.selItem) contains all items that have been selected so I don't know which item was the last to be added (which is the one I want to remove).

Initially I was using a Directive - but had the same problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: Each time a new item is selected `itemChange()` is called.  So if they select one at a time you can track the order of selections within `itemChange()`.  But if they select multiple items with one mouse drag then there's no way to tell which came first since they all happen at once.  Is there some reason you can't do a select per group?  That would sure make your life easier.

Comment: suggest using a select plugin that uses different html than `<select>` tag and gives you more control through plugin events API